# String Intern API doc

Tags: java, string

[java.lang.String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) API doc says

> Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

It tells, If the String object is not in pool, It will add the **same String object** to pool.
So in below code, why the output is not `true`?

```
String s1 = new String("abc");
String s2 = s1.intern();
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All string *literals* are automatically interned.
Therefore, `s1.intern()` returns the already-interned instance from `"abc"`, which is not `s1`.

To make a string without interning it, you can write `new String("a") + "bc"`.

Comment: `String s1 = new String("a")+"bc";
String s2 = s1.intern();
System.out.println(s1 == s2);`  This also returns false. Here which object went to pool?

Comment: @Sangeeth: Does `"abc"` appear anywhere in your source?

Comment: `s1` refers to an object with value `"abc"`. `s1.intern()` should add the same object to pool. right?

Comment: @Sangeeth: Not if the intern pool already contains a different instance with that value.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `"abc"` is already in the String pool: it was added to the `String` pool when you referred to the string constant `"abc"` to copy it into this new `String`.